# MySQL function for emulating Java's LocalDate.fromEpochDay()

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

as I have some legacy values in my MySQL database that stand for a java.time.LocalDate value, I wanted to create a conversion function to get back the correct MySQL `DATE` value. The initial values were generated via `LocalDate.toEpochDay()`. So I looked at the corresponding `LocalDate.ofEpochDay(long epochDay)` method (see [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java#l313)) and tried to translate it. But my translation produces negative days which I cannot interpret.

Does anyone have an idea why the following function does not work?

```
create function fromEpochDays(days bigint)
RETURNS date DETERMINISTIC
--RETURNS varchar(50) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE dom bigint;
    DECLARE month bigint;
    DECLARE year bigint;
    DECLARE zeroDay bigint;
    DECLARE adjust bigint;
    DECLARE daysPerCycle bigint;
    DECLARE adjustCycles bigint;
    DECLARE yearEst bigint;
    DECLARE doyEst bigint;
    DECLARE marchDoy0 bigint;
    DECLARE marchMonth0 bigint;
    DECLARE dateToParse CHAR(100);
    DECLARE valToCheck CHAR(100);

    SET daysPerCycle = 146097;
    SET adjustCycles = 0;
    SET adjust = 0;

    SET zeroDay = days + 719528 - 60;
    IF zeroDay < 0 THEN
        SET adjustCycles = (zeroDay + 1) / daysPerCycle - 1;
        SET adjust = adjustCycles * 400;
        SET zeroDay = zeroDay + (-adjustCycles * daysPerCycle);
    END IF;

    SET yearEst = (400 * zeroDay + 591) / daysPerCycle;
    SET doyEst = zeroDay - (365 * yearEst + yearEst / 4 - yearEst / 100 + yearEst / 400);
    IF doyEst < 0 THEN
        SET yearEst = yearEst - 1;
        SET doyEst = zeroDay - (365 * yearEst + yearEst / 4 - yearEst / 100 + yearEst / 400);
    END IF;
    
    SET yearEst = yearEst + adjust;
    SET marchDoy0 = doyEst;
    SET marchMonth0 = (marchDoy0 * 5 + 2) / 153;
    SET month = MOD((marchMonth0 + 2),12) + 1;
    SET dom = marchDoy0 - (marchMonth0 * 306 + 5) / 10 + 1;
    SET year = yearEst + marchMonth0 / 10;
    SET dateToParse = concat(cast(dom as char(20)),',',cast(month as char(20)),',',cast(year as char(20)));
    return STR_TO_DATE(dateToParse,'%d,%m,%Y');
END;
```

If I change the function to return only the variable `dateToParse` and call it with different values I get the following:

```
select
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(12),
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(13),
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(14),
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(15),
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(16),
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(29),
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(30),
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(31),
 fromEpochDays_AsChar(32)
```

```
fromEpochDays_AsChar(12)    13,1,1970
fromEpochDays_AsChar(13)    14,1,1970
fromEpochDays_AsChar(14)    15,1,1970
fromEpochDays_AsChar(15)    -15,2,1970
fromEpochDays_AsChar(16)    -14,2,1970
fromEpochDays_AsChar(29)    -1,2,1970
fromEpochDays_AsChar(30)    0,2,1970
fromEpochDays_AsChar(31)    1,2,1970
fromEpochDays_AsChar(32)    2,2,1970
```

Values from 0 to 14 yield correct values but the following look obviously weird ... Looks like only the first half of the month is computed correctly.

Comment: try to calculate the new date with     DECLARE result_date DATE;     select  DATE_ADD("1970-01-01", INTERVAL days DAY) into result_date;

Comment: @BUcorp Thanks for your comment! I use this now as a work around. But I really like to know what I did wrong there as I spend several time on this function. Maybe it is a limitiation in MySQL in computing with `bigint`?

Comment: honestly i don't know but i posted the answer as function mysql. let me know if you solve it (remember to flag as answered ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i said maybe try to simplify like this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` FUNCTION `fromEpochDays`(days INTEGER) RETURNS date
BEGIN

DECLARE result_date DATE; 
select DATE_ADD("1970-01-01", INTERVAL days DAY) into result_date;

RETURN result_date;
END
```